# Under the help dropdown on each StackExchange page, should we add the name/abbreviation of the community to the term "Meta"

Tags: feature-request, help-center, menu-bar

I propose that under the help dropdown near the top of the page (next to reputation, at least in the desktop interface), the third entry, which says "**Meta**" in most (all?) communities other than here on Meta (where it says "What is Meta") should be changed to clarify that it targets the specific community Meta rather than the overall Meta.
This could be achieved by adding the community name (or perhaps an abbreviation for long community names) before Meta (e.g., "**Physics Meta**" or "**UX Meta**" or "**ELL Meta**".

Additionally, the sub-description of "discuss workings and policies of this site" only adds ambiguity.  "site" could mean the overall network website, or the topic's website.  If anything, it seems "site" might actually suggest the entire website is the target, since we have the term "community" specifically for the separate topic websites.

So in addition, we should at the very least we change the word "site" to say "community" in the description.
However, we can also change "this site" to the name of the community, either as a companion to enhancing the actual link text, or as an alternative.

With the help menu already a confusing mix of scopes [Tour, About Us, and Business inform only on SE as a whole, while Help Center (ideally) and Meta aim towards community-specific information)], and with this site being geared towards informing, it would seem only natural for us to prioritize removing such ambiguities.

Though this tweak aims immediately towards helping established users, who would most likely know the existence of both Meta sites and be most seeking to quickly choose their intended target, it really is of benefit to anyone who may click on the link, helping all users better understand the structure of Stack Exchange.

I wish to see the navigation and help at Stack Exchange improved, and hopefully this recommendation can be a small step towards doing so.  Cheers!

Comment: Could this perhaps be difficult to implement in the current software?  Given that the overall Meta does have a distinct description, probably not?

Comment: Fwiw I never found any of the current wording to be confusing and I like it how it is now. Not saying the request is unreasonable, just providing a data point.